# How to delete/remove unused eclipse jpa connection configuration

Tags: eclipse, jpa

I'm getting the following error when opening my workspace:

> Could not connect to New Derby.
>   Error creating SQL Model Connection connection to New Derby. (Error: Failed to create database

I pinpoint the error due to the "New Derby" configuration exist in my jpa connection setting i previously created but not completeley done correctly due to unable to create the db (which is due to something else..)

I manged to create another connection setting, but had these uncompleted settings bugging me.

Is there a way to remove them?
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I deleted the unnecessary configurations in the Data Source Explorer view.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck JPA facet, delete persist.xml and remove conection from Data source explorer.
[image]

[image]